# SpelEvaluationException Method cannot be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-el, spelevaluationexception

I am facing with the next problem, when I am trying to pass the User to the service method using SpEL,

```
evaluate expression="commonService.userTest(user)" result="flowScope.user"
```

spring throws me the following exception:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 14): Method call: Method userTest(com.x.domain.common.User) cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114 type

But when I am passing a plain text instead of the User object,

```
evaluate expression="commonService.userTest('Hello')" result="flowScope.user"
```

There are no errors.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 5)
    private String password;
}

@Service("commonService")
public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public User userTest(String name) {
        User user = createUser();
        user.setUsername(name);
        return user;
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public User userTest(User user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update #2 - Workaround**

Removing DevTools dependency solved the problem, but applying this solution [Spring Boot Dev Tools & Web Flow don't play nice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7912) but creating `spring-devtools.properties` under `src/main/resources/META-INF/` with the following line makes it works with no problem at all

```
restart.include.spring=/.*\.jar
```

Why I didn't this line as mentioned in the link:

```
restart.include.spring=/spring-.*\.jar
```

Because I got this exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webFlowConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'webMvcConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'springTemplateEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultTemplateResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf3Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver]: Factory method 'defaultTemplateResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver.setApplicationContext(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/thymeleaf/spring4/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver, have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext used in the signature
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at medicallab.MedicallabApplication.main(MedicallabApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'springTemplateEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultTemplateResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf3Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver]: Factory method 'defaultTemplateResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver.setApplicationContext(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/thymeleaf/spring4/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver, have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext used in the signature
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultTemplateResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf3Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver]: Factory method 'defaultTemplateResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver.setApplicationContext(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/thymeleaf/spring4/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver, have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext used in the signature
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultTemplateResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf3Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver]: Factory method 'defaultTemplateResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver.setApplicationContext(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/thymeleaf/spring4/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver, have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext used in the signature
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1316) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1180) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver]: Factory method 'defaultTemplateResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver.setApplicationContext(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/thymeleaf/spring4/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver, have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext used in the signature
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver.setApplicationContext(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/thymeleaf/spring4/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver, have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext used in the signature
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration.defaultTemplateResolver(AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration.java:70) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf3Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration.defaultTemplateResolver(ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java:140) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf3Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2a7a126.CGLIB$defaultTemplateResolver$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf3Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2a7a126$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7a53489b.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf3Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2a7a126.defaultTemplateResolver(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEA

SE]
... 76 common frames omitted
```

So I have to include all jars for now.
Hope this might help someone in the future, but please refer to **Update #1** because this might going to be solved in the future [Spring DevTools classloader limitations](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF-1690), *but that lead to LiveReload server doesn't run*.

---

**Update #1**

It seems this a DevTools issue ([Customizing the restart classloader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload)) which might be fixed soon [Spring DevTools classloader limitations](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF-1690). It is started in this issue [Spring Boot Dev Tools & Web Flow don't play nice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7912)

---

**Original Answer**

I had the same issue several times, I have done a test and I found that a weird behavior.

```
public class SomeModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7967970066125990593L;
    ...
}
```

CustomFlowAction.java

```
package app.flow;

public class CustomFlowAction {

    // Note here the paramter is of type Object, just to use casting instead of using the object directly to test if I have the correct one
    public boolean someAction(Object obj, RequestContext context) {
        SomeModel someModel = (SomeModel) obj;
        return true
    }

    public SomeModel prepareSomeModel() {
        return new SomeModel();
    }
}
```

(Flow Example 1) some-flow.xml

This example is using a spring bean, it works fine and someAction method returns true.

```
<flow ...>
  <view-state id="StateOne"  model="someModel">
    <transition on="next" to="StateTwo">
      <evaluate expression="customFlowAction.someAction(someModel, flowRequestContext)"></evaluate>
    </transition>
  </view-state>
</flow>
```

(Flow Example 2) some-flow.xml

This example is creating a new object from SomeModel and stores it flowScope, then uses it inside the template.

```
<flow ...>
  <on-start>
    <evaluate expression="submitRequestFlowAction.prepareSomeModel()" result="flowScope.someModel"></evaluate>
  </on-start>

  <view-state id="StateOne"  model="someModel">
    <transition on="next" to="StateTwo">
      <evaluate expression="customFlowAction.someAction(someModel, flowRequestContext)"></evaluate>
    </transition>
  </view-state>
</flow>
```

The output is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: app.flow.SomeModel cannot be cast to app.flow.SomeModel
```

Some guys guided me to there might be another classloader involved in the issue, and one told me this:

> Note that classloader is part of class types: class A, loaded by
>   classloader CL1, is not the same as class A loaded by classloader CL2,
>   even though the *actual A.class* might be the same file

Hope this would be helpful for you and anyone else in trouble like me :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error associated with retrieving an object from the database. To resolve this I made a service class that called the proxied object from withing a transaction and that solved it.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public User findOneByCustomerPersonalEmail(String email) {
    User user = userRepository.findOneByCustomerPersonalEmail(email);
    user.getCustomer(); //this line fills the proxied object
    return user;
}
```